# JavaScript: detect the moment when window is starting to change location

Tags: javascript, onload-event

I'm trying to detect the exact moment when the page leaves its current location and begins loading of a new one: immediately after clicking on a link or pressing "submit" or any other way.

I'm aware of "onload" event and several ways to make use of it, but that's not what I'm looking for: plenty of time can pass between 1) clicking on link and 2) firing "onload" event and I need to detect the moment after 1).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:  onbeforeunload or onunload

Answer (score 0):

I like using the `onhashchange` event:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    console.log("Hash changed");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v8j9F/

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange

Answer (score 0):

`onbeforeunload` is probably the earliest, it's described briefly [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/window.shtml)